# How to show looping sub event in Fullcalendar tooltip dynamically?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to show tooltip on hover an event in Fullcalendar plugin, but i want to show subevent only in the tooltip order by index.

If my json is like this:

```
[{
"title":"event A,
"start":"2020-07-29",
"end":"2020-07-29",
"extendedProps":{"subevent":"sub 1","subevent":"sub 2","subevent":"sub 3"},
}, {
"title":"event B,
"start":"2020-07-30",
"end":"2020-07-30",
"extendedProps":{"subevent":"sub 4","subevent":"sub 5"}]
```

and this is my eventMouseEnter:

```
eventMouseEnter: function(info) {
        var tis=info.el;
        var popup=info.event.extendedProps;
        var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="top:'+($(tis).offset().top-5)+'px;left:'+ 
($(tis).offset().left+($(tis).width())/2)+'px"><div>Name ' + popup.title + '</div><div>sub event ' + popup.subevent + '</div></div>';
        var $tooltip = $(tooltip).appendTo('body');
  }
```

How to show my sub event dynamically like this?
[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1i6x.jpg)

Thank You.

Best Regards,

Eka

Comment: What exact problem are you having with the code above?

Comment: @ADyson, I have attached an example tooltip picture.

Comment: Ok, that's what you want it to do, I understand that. My question is what exactly is the problem currently? What is going wrong when you run the code, compared to what you wanted it to do? And have you done any debugging to try and narrow down the issue?

Comment: I just know how to show 1 subevent. I do not know how to make looping in javascript to show all of my subevent.

Comment: Ok that's a bit clearer. so I started looking more closely and I just noticed that your extendedProps data is not valid - you've got multiple properties with the same name inside the same object. How is JavaScript supposed to tell them apart, do you expect? (I.e. when you refer to popup.subevent, how is it supposed to know which one of the three versions of that you're actually asking for??) You need to define an _array_ of sub-events within there. Then it will be easy to loop through

Comment: do you mean some thing like this? "extendedProps":{"itenery":"[sub 1,sub 2,sub 3]"}, Can you give me an example how to read this array, please?

Comment: yes something like that. You read it with a loop, just like any array. Do you know how to make a loop in JavaScript? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Okay, I have extendedProps":{"itenery":["sub 1","sub 2"]}, then                                        eventMouseEnter: function(info) {
            var tis=info.el;
            var popup=info.event.extendedProps.itenery;
            //var arrayLength = popup.length; -->this is undefined, how to know how many members of my array?                                                                                             },

Comment: Your code is correct by the looks of it. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ExPRZBQ - it works. If you're getting undefined, then I can only assume that somehow your event doesn't have the correct values in extendedProps, despite what you've shown.

Comment: Why did i get an error? How should i fix to write this, please?                                                 var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="top:'+($(tis).offset().top-5)+'px;left:'+($(tis).offset().left+($(tis).width())/2)+'px"><div>' + popup.mainevent + '</div><div>' + for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {popup.itenery} + '</div></div>';
            var $tooltip = $(tooltip).appendTo('body');

Comment: Are you still getting the same "undefined" error as before?

Comment: No. it has solved, i just typed wrong code. it produced new error when i put for looping inside <div>

Comment: Ok. So what exactly is the error? If you have an error and you want me to fix it, it makes sense to tell me what the error is!

Comment: Would you like to check it out please? https://jsfiddle.net/ekajaya/hqo1ku2s/59/

Comment: You had some files and code which didn't need to be there. Now it's better, the logging is working: https://jsfiddle.net/edy8sm4j/

Comment: but, the tooltip still not work.

Comment: I didn't say it would, I just said it wasn't full of unnecessary stuff which was making it crash. I don't have time right now to figure the rest out, maybe tomorrow I will. In the meantime it might be easier for you to get it working, now the errors are gone

Comment: @ADyson I have solve this case use for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {      
              var str = detail.join('<br/><br/> ');
              console.log(str);
            }                                                                                                                                    Thank You so much for your help.

Comment: If you solved it please write your full solution below in the Answers section, for the benefit of others (and for your benefit - if people find it useful, they will give you upvotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eventMouseEnter: function(info) {
        var tis=info.el;
        var popup=info.event.extendedProps;
        var detail=info.event.extendedProps.itenery;
        var arrayLength = detail.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {      
          var str = detail.join('<br/><br/> ');
        }
        var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="top:'+ 
($(tis).offset().top-5)+'px;left:'+($(tis).offset().left+($(tis).width())/2)+'px"> 
<div>' + popup.title + '</div><div>' + str + '</div></div>';
        var $tooltip = $(tooltip).appendTo('body');
  }
```